# Objective-c: giving up on Core Data, SQlite3 - going with .plist. Am I wrong?

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data, plist

I developing my first iOS app. It is actually a port of an Android app I wrote recently.
I really stumbled on the database portion!

It is a simple database storing several strings/ints for each row. SQLite3 on Android was a piece of cake!

I have tried learning Core Data, Core Data Stack, SQLite3 tutorials...Things are written for different version of XCode, do not use garbage collection, plain typos or just too unfamiliar.

I do not expect to store more than ~100K of data.
Should I use XML/plist instead, or is Core Data worth time investment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use CoreData to "fetch data from a sqlite database". If you need to "fetch data from a sqlite database" use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or similar. FMDB is a wrapper around sqlite3 for iOS. You should be able to copy your `select` statements right across and wrap them into FMDB.

Using CoreData but thinking in SQL language only creates confusion. If you intent to use CoreData then better ignore the fact that CoreData is using a sqlite db as persistent storage and forget everything you know about sql language.

CoreData is an Object Graph framework not a database interface. It happens to store data to a sqlite db as default but from a programmer point of view the usage is in terms of objects. it is not in terms of rows and tables.

Coming back to FMDB. There, a database is opened with:

`FMDatabase *theDatabase = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:pathToDB];`

Stored rows are retrieved with a `select` statement:

`FMResultSet *setOfRows = [db executeQuery:@"select * from tableName where attribute = ?", @"some criteria'"];`

Then iterate through the retrieved rows using a `while`:

```
while ([setOfRows next]) {
    NSLog(@"%d %@ %@ %f", // simply print to the console
          [rs intForColumn:@"integerColumn"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"attribute"],
          [rs dateForColumn:@"dateColumn"],
          [rs doubleForColumn:@"doubleValue"]); 
}
```

You should be able to keep all the work that went into designing your database layout under android. Just wrap the access part. For more on the syntax there is a good readme at the github page for [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Comment: Thank you for great response!

Is there a simplistic explanation of how CoreData works? Like the beaten car/factory analogy for classes/objects?

Or those things are beyond simple explanation?

Comment: I am not aware of simplistic explanation. Most tutorials out there are trying to cover way too much, thus making it rather complex.

Answer (score 3):

Fast solution is to use plain sqlite3 as you did earlier.

Core Data works great, but it requires deep understanding what are you doing, and how it works. It gives you some flexibility, auto migrations, and lots of another features. But it also contain a lot of places where you could shoot yourself in the leg.

I had troubles with many small things. For example auto migration from v.1 -> v.2 works well and v.2 -> v.3 works well too. but it can't migrate from v.1 -> v.3 itself.